# How to include a plain js library in Ionic 2 typescript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have seen similar posts to this, but none have helped me.

I have an ionic 2 project, and am using Typescript 2 (beta)

I thought I was getting there, but sadly I think I still don't understand how Typescript/Browserfy work together to include the actual js files into `app.bundle.js` in the Ionic 2 build.

This time I want to use the library [mqtt](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/) that has no type definition file . I have installed the js library and see it in the node_modules.

Near the end of `mqtt.js` (the file listed as the `main` attribute in the package.json file of the node package) I see some exports such as

```
// Expose MqttClient
module.exports.MqttClient = MqttClient;
module.exports.Client = MqttClient;
module.exports.Store = Store;

// Expose servers
module.exports.Server = MqttServer;
module.exports.MqttServer = MqttServer;
module.exports.SecureServer = MqttSecureServer;
module.exports.MqttSecureServer = MqttSecureServer;

// Expose Connection
module.exports.MqttConnection = MqttConnection;
```

So I want to use this MqttClient in one of my pages.

When I build I do NOT see this MqttClient in app.bubdle.js

If I add 'node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js'into ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript folder index.js as below

```
var defaultOptions = {
  watch: false,
  src: ['./app/app.ts', './typings/index.d.ts', 'node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js' <--- I added this],
  outputPath: 'www/build/js/',
```

Now when I look into app.bundle.js I do see module.exports.MqttClient = MqttClient; I do not see MqttServer (so some of the exports get in app.bundle.js, but not others!

**Question 1** is why I don't see all the exports?

**Question 2** - the most import question, is, how can I now import/use this in my Ionic page?

I have tried adding (as suggested elsewhere)

```
  declare var MqttClient: any;
```

and then

```
let client = new MqttClient();
```

but MqttClient is always undefined

Do I need to "require" it using a loader? I did think as we are using Typescript / Browserfy that I won't need a loader (eg Systemjs)

Any help greatly appreciated! Completely stumped on what to do here!

Comment: I think this is one of the issues that messed me up the most lately. It takes time just to understand that the d.ts files won't create themselves out of thin air :) Did you solve it? I mean - adding a js to the build?

Comment: I never got the above library working (the type definition also seemed out of sync with it). I did get this one.. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/paho/releases/1.0.2/paho.javascript-1.0.2.zip Just manually included the mqttws31.js. Added to the path in src of the ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript (similar to above). Then in my TS file just below the other imports, I added `declare var Paho: any;` and then `this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", Number(location.port), "clientId");` to use (no typings). I am still looking into all this in general though....

Comment: A colegue of mine told me that you cannot just include the file under the html/js folder of your project, but you indeed need to fix the project gulp file to incorporate the js files you need into the code. Of course - no typings are available (to date), so you'll just have to use the "declare let" trick with a javascript object (works like a charm!)

Comment: @rubmz Yes that seems correct, so if using Ionic we include the js source in `gulp-browserify-typescript folder index.js`. The one thing that I am still not sure about is when you DO have a typing files installed, you do not seem to need to do the above (eg using the D3 and C3 libs). I am assuming when the TS compiler does  find the typing,  it then knows to  search the node_modules folder for the actual js file and then include this.  I don't know this to be correct,  just my assumption at this stage.

Comment: Sure if you have the TS available (which is currently not the case)